# How to appeal or remove the credit check taken on a Lender?

Tags: united-states, credit-score, credit-history

I was working with a car dealer to purchase a car. I realized that , Dealer ran the credit check and applied for a lender which i wasn't aware. I was hoping to get loan from LenderA. But dealer was pursuing me to proceed for LenderB.

So, I dropped the purchase process. My question is, How to appeal or remove the credit check taken on Lender A ? That check / application was happened without my knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't remove the credit check with either lender because they happened.

Car dealerships are notoriously other than honest, however in this case they are probably protected.  The paperwork you filled out probably gave them license to shop your loan to whoever they wished.

The best solution here is to not have car loan.  Doing so is very detrimental to your future self, financially.

However, if you choose to be car wealthy, then you could have just applied to directly with the lender of your choice.  Even places like Ford Credit will allow you to apply directly.

Comment: Thank you for the details. Looks like whatever happened will not be able to replace at this moment. So, i will have to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

The credit check will probably not hurt your credit score. The scoring models expect that similar checks done in a short window of time count as one inquiry. They know that a smart consumer has to shop for the best loan, therefore it would be harsh to punish their score at the exact moment they need to take advantage of their score.

So even if you get the inquiry removed (which I highly doubt it will be removed) the next dealership will trigger a hard pull.